# Does Redis cache supports Native sql Api

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis-cache

I am using apache ignite for my application now I wanted to migrate to redis-cache but I used ignite query api to fetch data. Is there any possible way I can use the same queries just by changing dependencies from ignite to redis-cache?

Is there any alternative tool where i can use in AWS cloud platform which supports Native SQL API?

Comment: No Redis does not. Why do you want stop using ignte ?

Comment: I am migrating our on-premiss application to cloud where Ignite is not available as managed service on AWS. So, planned to move to redis but we have leveraged query language from ignite which is not available in redis. So if you have any solution or alternative where I can use querying type caching tool on cloud let me know. @Mr_Thorynque

Comment: If you want managed ( and payed) solution you can take a look to gridgrain https://www.gridgain.com/products/in-memory-computing-platform it's based on apache ignite.